# Compute P(XY) given P(x) and P(y)

Tags: probability, density-function, cumulative-distribution-function

Given two random variables x and y. Their PDFs P(x) and P(y) are known. However, if we do not assume the independence between x and y, how can we represent the Cumulative Distribution Function F(xy) (yes, x multiplied by y).

I am not familiar with probability theory, and I have attempted to write some double integral begin with $\textrm{p(xy<=Z)=p(y<=Z/x)}$ but I am still very confused...

Could anyone please give me some hints? highly appreciate it!

Comment: The problem as you have stated it is impossible. You cannot derive the cdf of xy from the two marginal distributions. You would instead need to know the joint distribution.

Comment: Thanks for your attention and reply! Could you please tell me the mathematical equation to compute P(xy) given P(x,y)?

Comment: It depends on how you *represent* the joint distribution.  Are you working with a specific example?  (If not, maybe you should be...)